# How to set internationalization in ember JS with a URL parameter or a variable in route/template

Tags: ember.js, internationalization

I have a readymade ember app on which i am working. It already has a i18n.js file in the initializer folder and has few lines of code as below

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export function initialize() {
Ember.I18n.translations = TRANSLATIONS.en;
}

 var TRANSLATIONS = {
  en: {
      hello: 'Hello'
  },
  fr: {
      hello : 'bonjour' 
  }
 };

 export default {
    name: 'i18n',
    initialize: initialize,
    before: '',
    after: ''
 };
```

My app has 3 landing pages(french/english/spanish), so when the url for english landing page is clicked i should pass the 'en' parameter to the i18n.js.

My problem is that i18n.js is loaded initially itself when the app loads and it sets to 'en' , after that i am not able to access it and modify to a different value.

I am new to ember and UI development, i went through the guides but was not able to find a specific example for my case

Answer (score 0):

You can access the i18n in your application route , You can set there like below.

`this.set('i18n.locale', langCodeYouWantToSet);`

This should be set in the `beforeModel` of the application route , so that your application loads with the proper language.

Comment: hi, i was able to do as you suggested, but i had to import the initialize method in i18 to my application route.